# Unable to find suitable Visual Studio Toolchain - Flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, exception

I am using Visual Studio Code, and getting this: Exception: Unable to find suitable Visual Studio toolchain. Please run `flutter doctor` for more details.

[image: Error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to find suitable Visual Studio toolchain. Please run \`flutter doctor\` for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60334570/unable-to-find-suitable-visual-studio-toolchain-please-run-flutter-doctor-for)

Answer (score 1):

You most likely didn't install the exact version of the Windows 10 SDK, I think it can be a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution I figured out myself:**

1. Go to this location: " C:\Users\yourUserName "
2. Delete the folder ".gradle" completely from this directory.
3. Run the code again in VS Code by "flutter run" or "F5", then it will recreate the ".gradle" folder in the same directory and fix the issue.

*Problem Solved, Enjoy!*